# Find the probability of a face of a loaded die.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a die, for which all faces have the same probability, except for one face. I know in advance which face is different, let's say it's the 6. My goal is to find the probability of that face by tossing the die $n$ times and counting how many times it lands on the loaded face.

Let's suppose I rolled the die $n = 1000$ times and it landed $k = 250$ times on the 6. The obvious answer would be that the probability of landing on the 6 is $\frac{k}{n} = \frac{1}{4}$. But the real probability ($\frac{k}{n}$ after infinitely many tosses) could be different. It could also be only $\frac{1}{8}$ but I got extremely lucky in this case and the die landed 250 out of 1000 times on the 6. However, this would be extremely unlikely, but how unlikely? How to calculate the probability, that x% is the real probability of the die? I'd like to have a function *f(x) = probability that x is the real probability of the die*, with the parameters $n$ and $k$. I think the maximum of this function should be at $\frac{k}{n}$, but I'm not sure exactly how the function would look.

Also, I'd like to give upper and lower bounds on the probability after $n$ tosses. I know that it's technically impossible since the die could land $k$ times on the 6 no matter what the real probability is (except if it's 0% or 100%). However, I could set the bounds in a way that they ignore extremely improbable events. So, I want to say that the real probability of the die is between a% and b%, with a probability of c%. I believe this can be solved using integrals, but how?

Comment: $\frac kn$ is the maximum-likelihood and so the "best guess" for $p$. However, the probability estimates you desire would require an a priori distribution. e.g., if we pulled the die from a bag with one specimen each for $p=0.1$, $p=0.2$, $\ldots$, $p=0.9$,  the answer would be different from a situation where the bag contain $k$ specimen for $p=\frac k{100}$, $k=1,\ldots, 99$. In the absence of any other guidance, we perhaps want to assume that $p$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Assuming a prior uniform distribution of $p$, let's say you got $k$ lands on $6$ out of a total of $n$ tries. Then the probability for the "landing 6" probability to fall between $a$ and $b$ is   $(\int_{a}^{b} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} dp)/\binom{n}{k}  $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number $X$ of 6's in your experiment with $n=1000$ rolls would be
be a binomial random variable with $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(100, p),$
where $p$ is the probability of the loaded face 6.

Using a frequentist approach, you could use this information to
make a 95% Wald confidence interval for $p$ of the form
$\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{1000}},$ where
$\hat p = X/n = 250/1000 = 0.25,$ as you say. Using R,
this computes to the interval $(0.223, 0.277).$ The Wald
interval does not give good results for small $n,$ but
for $n = 1000,$ it gives a good interval estimate of the
probability $p$ of the loaded face.

```
n = 1000;  x = 250
p.hat = x/n
CI = p.hat + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)/n)
CI
[1] 0.2231621 0.2768379
```

Taking the Bayesian approach suggested in the Comment of
@user3257842, you would have the prior distribution
$\mathsf{Unif}(0,1) \equiv \mathsf{Beta}(1,1).$
Your binomial likelihood function would be proportional
to $p^{250}(1-p)^{750}.$

Then by Bayes' Theorem the posterior distribution of $p$
would have a density function proportional to the product
of the above beta prior distribution and binomial likelihood
function. Fortunately, these two functions are mathematically
compatible (the technical term is 'conjugate') so it is
easy to see that the posterior density function is proportional
to $p^{1+250-1}(1-p)^{1+750 - 1},$ which matches the
function form of the $\mathsf{Beta}(251,751)$ density function.
Then a 95% posterior interval estimate (also called a 95%
'Bayesian
credible interval') is found to be $(0.224, 0.278)$ as shown below in R.

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 251, 751)
[1] 0.2241639 0.2777775
```

Unlike the frequentist confidence interval, the Bayesian credible
interval can be interpreted to apply directly to your biased die
---provided that you believe the prior distribution is reasonable.
Fortunately, with $n=1000$ rolls of the die you have so much
data that the influence of the uniform prior on the final result
is small.

*Notes:* (1) If you are not familiar with beta distributions,
see if you can find them in a textbook. Alternatively, see the
Wikipedia page on beta distributions.

(2) There are many styles of frequentist confidence
intervals for the binomial success probability. See the Wikipedia
page on binomial confidence intervals.

(2) Among the frequentist intervals in (1) is the Jeffreys interval, which
is derived from a Bayesian argument starting with the Jeffreys prior
distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(.5,.5).$ The 95% Jeffreys interval for your data (whether
interpreted as a frequentist confidence interval or as a Bayesian
credible interval) is $(0.224, 0.278)$ (rounded to three places). For technical reasons, many
Bayesians prefer to use $\mathsf{Beta}(.5,.5)$ instead of
$\mathsf{Beta}(1,1)$ as a 'noninformative' prior distribution (in
the absence of previous data or strong personal opinion).

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 250.5, 750.5)
[1] 0.2239111 0.2775336
```